# How to implement surface calculation of a elliptical cone and elliptical paraboloid (in R)?

Tags: r, math, statistics, geometry

How can I calculate the surface of an elliptical paraboloid in R, having only the two major axes a and b, and the height h?

Background: got a population of things which which resemble elliptical paraboloids. (Think of [hummocks](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Frost_upheaval.jpg), e.g.). What I'm statistically interested in is: how large is the mean and SD error I introduce when I approximate the surfaces of the population as rectangular (a * b) instead of properly modelling their surface? I could just go for a cone, but I've got some really long ellipses in that population of data. This made me look for how to calculate an [elliptical paraboloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticParaboloid.html), and and [elliptic cone](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCone.html). Which did not help me answering my question so far.

I can't translate the neither Wolfram nor Wikipedia properly, just started for the cone with

```
paraboloid.surf <- function(a,b,h){2*a*sqrt(b^2+h^2)* E * sqrt((1-b^2/a^2)/(1+b^2/a^2))}
```

without knowing how to calculate E, or even understanding if this is E multiplied by the term, or a function E(k) of k = the term.

Can somebody help me out and provide some code? I would be interested in both the conical as the parabolical solution, but any is better than none. I hope this is really non-trivial, and I'm not totally stupid. =)

Comment: Why I'm voting to close. I don't think the problem is adequately defined as presented. You apparently want the ratio of the volume some ill-specified rectangle to the volume of some equally ill-specified truncated ellipsoid.

Comment: This is a perfectly good question, and also extremely "non-trivial". There is no closed form solution for the area of an elliptical paraboloid. And most solutions require evaluation of a double integral, which is difficult in R.

Comment: @jlhoward I think there is a closed form soln for the volume.

Comment: I think  comments and answers so far prove that the question was unclear w.r.t. whether it was the volume or the surface area that was the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assume you want the surface area of an elliptic paraboloid. The basic framework is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339621/surface-area-of-an-elliptic-paraboloid), from which the following image is taken.

[image]

So the question is how to compute this in R? The hardest part is the double integral, which can be evaluated using the `adaptIntegrate(...)` function in the `cubature` package.

```
A <- function(a,b,h) {
  require(cubature)
  integrand <- function(x,a,b){
    u <- x[1]
    v <- x[2]
    E <- 1+((a*cos(v))^2 + (b*sin(v))^2)/(4*u)
    F <- (b^2 - a^2)*sin(2*v)/4
    G <- u*((a*sin(v))^2+(b*cos(v))^2)
    return(sqrt(E*G-F^2))
  }
  adaptIntegrate(integrand, 
                 lowerLimit=c(0,0), upperLimit=c(h,2*pi), a=a,b=b)$integral
}
```

We can confirm this by noting that when

> a = b = h = 1
>
> E = 1 + 1/4u
>
> F = 0
>
> G = u
>
> A = 2π ∫du sqrt(u+1/4)

Which can be evaluated in closed form as:

> A = 4π/3 [ (5/4)<sup>3/2</sup> - (1/4)<sup>3/2</sup> ] = 5.330414

```
A(1,1,1)
# [1] 5.330413
(4*pi/3)*((5/4)^(3/2) - (1/4)^(3/2))
# [1] 5.330414
```

Comment: Brilliant, and lucidly coded. Still challenging (on the fly: trouble understanding how to get angles u and v), but  this seems to be *exactly* the solution I was looking for. 
Thanks a million! Going to look into the as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_paraboloid the defining equation for an elliptic parabola is `z/c = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2`. We can transform this to make a hill with height 'h' and base at `z=0` being an ellipse.

For a elliptic parabola

```
   z = h*(1 - ((x/a)^2+(y/b)^2)).
```

Where `a` and `b` are the semi-major and semi-minor axis of the ellipse generated by cutting the cone by z=0 and `h` is the height of the point above (0,0).

For a elliptical cone

```
   z = h*(1 - sqrt((x/a)^2+(y/b)^2))`.
```

Where `a` and `b` are the semi-major and semi-minor axis of the ellipse generated by cutting the cone by `z=0`.

To plot both you need to clip by the plane `z=0` use `max(0,h*(1 - ((x/a)^2+(y/b)^2))`.

### Volumes

The area of an ellipse is `pi a b`, the volume of a cone is `1/3 basearea * h` so volume of the cone is

```
    1/3 pi a b h.
```

As mentioned elsewhere the volume of the elliptic paraboloid is a bit tricky.
We can try doing it by slicing in the z-direction.

```
    int_{z=0}^{h} area of ellipse at height z dz.
```

If the ellipse at height z has semis `a(z)` and `b(z)` then the area is

```
    A(z) = pi a(z) b(z).
```

To find the `a(z)` and `b(z)` slice the paraboloid by the planes `y=0`, `x=0`, these give two parabolas `z = h *(1 - (x/a)^2)`, `z = h *(1 - (y/b)^2)`. Rearrange `z/h = 1 - (x/a)^2`, `(x/a)^2 = 1 - z/h` `x/a = sqrt(1-z/h)` `x=a*sqrt(1-z/h)` this is our `a(z)`. Similary `b(z)=b*sqrt(1-z/h)`. The area of the ellipse at height z is

```
 A(z) = pi a(z) b(z)
      = pi a sqrt(1-z/h) b sqrt(1-z/h) 
      = pi a b (1-z/h)
```

Integrate

```
 int_{z=0}^h pi a b (1-z/h)
    = pi a b [z - z^2/(2 h)]_0^h
    = pi a b (h - h^2/(2 h))
    = 1/2 pi a b h
```

remarkably simple.

For comparison the volume of the cuboid with height `h` and lengths `2a` and `2b` would be

```
    4 a b h.
```

### Surface areas

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind the circumference of a ellipse with semi-major axis `a` and eccentricity `e` is

```
    4 a E(e)
```

where `E(e)` is a complete Elliptical integral of the second kind. The eccentricity `e` is

```
    e = sqrt( 1 - b^2/a^2 ).
```

In both the cone and elliptic paraboloid cases the eccentricity is constant for all horizontal slices. The integrals for surface areas then simplify nicely. For the cone
`a(z) = a * ( h - z)`. So

```
    int_z 4 a(z) E(e) dz
       = 4 E(e) int_z a(z) dz
       = 4 E(e) int_{z=0}^h a * (h -z ) dz
       = 4 a E(e) int_{z=0}^h h - z dz
       = 4 a E(e) [h z - z^2/2]_{z=0}^h
       = 4 a E(e) h^2/2 
       = 2 a E(e) h^2
```

For the elliptic paraboloid `a(z)=a*sqrt(1-z/h)` and the integral is

```
    int_z 4 a(z) E(e) dz
       = 4 E(e) int_z a(z) dz
       = 4 E(e) int_{z=0}^h a * sqrt(1-z/h) dz
```

change variables with `w=1-z/h` limits are 1 and 0 `dz/dw = -h` so

```
       = 4 E(e) int_{w=1}^0 a * sqrt(w) * -h dw
       = 4 a E(e) h int_{w=0}^1 sqrt(w) dw      // switching limits round
       = 4 a E(e) h [ 2 w^(3/2) /3]_{w=0}^1
       = 8/3 a E(e) h.
```

### Multivariate normal distribution

An alternative and more standard model is as a 2D gaussian https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function

```
    z = 1/(2 pi a b) exp( -( (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 )/2).
```

This will look pretty close to the paraboloid apart from at the base.

Comment: OP asked for the surface area of a parabolic ellispoid with parameters a, b, h. Are you saying this is 1/2 * pi *a * b * h ??

Comment: @jlhoward  No, the volume of the parabolic ellipsoid. Its a bit hard to see quite what the OP questions really is. It looks like he is trying to generate a probability density function, pdf(x,y) for this you want the double integral to be 1. It looks like the surface area can be given in terms of Elliptic integrals. I'll update my answer with this.